# Is there a way get/add animation to objects using a Google Apps Script in Google Slides?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-slides-api

When formatting a Google Slides presentation using a Google Apps Script, is there any way to access and/or modify the data regarding animations of objects (text boxes, shapes, images, etc.) in order to add, delete, or modify animations?

Answer (score 3):

There is currently no way to get/set animations or transitions using Google Apps Script (that I can see). It could be requested on their [issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=componentid:191640%20status:open).